# What is the best way to structure an if statement for two conditions with an action each, and an action for both?

Tags: logic, conditional-statements

When i have two conditions, with an action for each condition, and an action for both conditions if one is true,

Sometimes I do this

```
if (cond1 or cond2)
    if (cond1)
        do act 1
    if (cond2)
        do act 2
    do always
```

Sometimes I do this

```
if (cond1)
    do act 1
    do always
if (cond2)
    do act 2
    do always
```

But I would really like to do this

```
if (cond1)
    do act 1
or if (cond2)
    do act 2
then
    do always
```

Does the last method exist in any language, or is there a preferred method for handling this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
if (cond1)
    do act 1
if (cond2)
    do act 2
if (cond1 or cond2)
   do always
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this, and it is unwieldy to extract the common
things into another function, you could use a macro like this
(untested, Common Lisp):

```
(defmacro cond-any (clauses)
  (let ((any-clause (gensym "any")))
    `(let ((,any-clause nil))
       (cond ,@(mapcar (lambda (clause)
                         (if (eq (first clause) :any-after)
                             (setf any-clause (rest clause))
                             (append clause any-clause)))
                       clauses)))))
```

This gives you the ability to do this:

```
(cond-any (:any-after do-always)
          (cond1 do-1)
          (cond2 do-2))
```

The keyword `:any-after` then means "if any of the subsequent conditions
are true, append this after its then-part".

Answer (score 1):

Prefer something that does not involve duplicate code as much as possible.

This alternative might be the most flexible, with minimal duplication:

```
var := false

if (cond1)
    do act 1
    var := true

if (cond2)
    do act 2
    var := true

if (var)
    do always
```

You may find that there are more times that you want var set, or that as time goes by and the number of "ifs" that you want to "do always" grows.  This way avoids "complex" and/or statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
return unless (cond1 or cond2)
if (cond1)
    do_act 1
if (cond2)
    do_act 2
do_always
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple If statements lead to more time consumption as each is evaluated separately. To avoid this make use of if else if ladder to reduce time. My suggestion :-

```
if(cond1 AND cond2)
       do act 1
       do act 2
       do always
else if (cond1 OR cond2)
       if(cond1)
           do act 1
       else
           do act 2 
       do always
```

In all your solutions, the number of comparisons are a minimum of 2. But in this particular solution, the minimum is 1 . So ideally this should be the best fit.

Comment: I don't like this. The logic isn't straightfoward, lots of code is duplicated and often the larger code size will bite more than the one comparison you saved...